# How to Display Specific Related Posts using Timber & ACF?

Tags: twig, timber

I am currently new to Timber.

Here's the code:

**view.twig**

```
{# mobile related list #}
{% if related %}
<div class="hide-for-large">
  {% include 'project/_related-list.twig' %}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**_related-list.twig**

```
<aside class="related-projects">
  <h2 class="related-projects__header">Related {{plural_post_type|default('Projects')}}</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for post in related %}
    <li class="related-projects__thumb tease--{{post.post_type}} tease tease--caption tease--show-caption-on-hover tease--show-overlay-on-hover tease--has-overlay">
      {% include 'partials/tease.twig' %}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</aside>
```

**tease.twig**

```
  <a href="{{post.link}}" class="tease__wrap">
  {% block content %}
    <div class="tease__caption">
      <h3 class="tease__title">
        {{post.title}}
      </h3>
    </div>
    {% if post.get_thumbnail %}
      <img class="tease__thumb b-lazy" data-object-fit="cover" data-pin-nopin="true" data-srcset="{{post.thumbnail.srcset}}"   data-src="{{post.thumbnail.src('large')}}" sizes="(min-width: 64em) 25vw, 100vw" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" />
    {% else %}
      <img class="tease__thumb"  src="{{theme.link}}/assets/img/ph-800x535.png">
    {% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
  </a>
```

The current setup displays the related post randomly. How do I change this to display the selected related post?

[sample image of test post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6nT9.png)

Comment: Can you also show us how your PHP file looks like? Especially the part where you define `related`.

Comment: Here is the code: https://codeshare.io/arABYZ

Comment: Cool, that definitely helps. It would be best if you could also include that link in your question (for that, you can edit your question). Could you also describe how ACF plays into this? In your question, you mention a "selected related post". Where do you select that? Do you have an ACF field where a user can select one or more related posts?

Comment: Hi Gchtr, here is the link: https://www.activemetal.com.au/projects/baker-mckenzie/

Comment: Yes, we've used the related post, they could select the related post, but it doesn't show since it only gets the related post via taxonomy.
ACF - Field: https://imgur.com/s9QblEJ
Post Contents: https://imgur.com/yFnUr1o

Comment: @Gchtr, will still be able to help mo on this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t understand the difference between your `specific-related-posts` field and the `related_posts` field. I’m assuming that you get 3 random related posts by default, but when any number of `related_posts` is set in the ACF field, you’ll want them to be included first, in that particular order.

First, I’d get the array of post IDs from the `related_posts` field. If you have selected post objects as a return value, I’d select only object IDs as a return value in your field group settings.

```php
$related = $post->meta( 'related_posts' );
```

And then, we convert them to Timber posts.

```php
$related_posts = Timber::get_posts( $related );
```

Then, you would build your query in a way that it

- excludes the posts that are already selected.
- fills up the rest of the posts with random posts.

```php
// Run additional query only if we don’t already have enough posts.
if ( count( $related ) < 3 ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => $post->post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => 3 - count( $related ),
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
        'post__not_in'   => array( $post->ID ),
        'tax_query'      => $tax_query,
    );

    // Append additional posts to already existing Timber posts array.
    $related_posts = array_merge(
        $related_posts,
        Timber::get_posts( $args )
    );
}

$context['related'] = $related_posts;
```

Now, we’re actually running two queries. First, when we convert the post IDs from `related_posts` to Timber posts and then again when we get random posts. We usually want to avoid that. You could run it in one query by using the `post__in` parameter. But in your case, you’re also using `rand` for ordering, which would mix up your order selected in your ACF field. As long as you don’t run into performance issues, I wouldn’t bother running two queries in this particular case.

Comment: Hi Gchtr, thank you for this, I'll try this out first. I will update you. 


Thanks again!